# train_dreambooth.py: error: the following arguments are required:

Tags: stable-diffusion

I'm trying to fit train SD 1.5 with DreamBooth with prior preservation following the  steps from https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers/tree/main/examples/dreambooth
But i'm receiving an error:

```
train_dreambooth.py: error: the following arguments are required: --pretrained_model_name_or_path, --instance_data_dir, --instance_prompt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/myuser/miniconda3/envs/dbooth/bin/accelerate", line 10, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/myuser/miniconda3/envs/dbooth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/accelerate/commands/accelerate_cli.py", line 45, in main
args.func(args)
File "/home/myuser/miniconda3/envs/dbooth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 1104, in launch_command
simple_launcher(args)
File "/home/myuser/miniconda3/envs/dbooth/lib/python3.7/site-packages/accelerate/commands/launch.py", line 567, in simple_launcher
raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode=process.returncode, cmd=cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/myuser/miniconda3/envs/dbooth/bin/python3.7', 'train_dreambooth.py']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

This is my script.sh for make the training:

```
#!/bin/bash
export MODEL_NAME="v1-5-pruned.ckpt"
export INSTANCE_DIR="retocadas"
export CLASS_DIR="person_ddim"
export OUTPUT_DIR="salida"

accelerate launch train_dreambooth.py \
--pretrained_model_name_or_path=$MODEL_NAME \
--instance_data_dir=$INSTANCE_DIR \
--class_data_dir=$CLASS_DIR \
--output_dir=$OUTPUT_DIR \
--with_prior_preservation --prior_loss_weight=1.0 \
--instance_prompt="AnUniqueExample" \
--class_prompt="person" \
--resolution=512 \
--train_batch_size=1 \
--gradient_accumulation_steps=2 --gradient_checkpointing \
--use_8bit_adam \
--learning_rate=5e-6 \
--lr_scheduler="constant" \
--lr_warmup_steps=0 \
--num_class_images=200 \
--max_train_steps=800
```

All files and paths indicated in the header are on the same path as the .sh file.
Someone can help me to find the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't want a CKPT file it wants a directory with all the components of the model. Go to hugging face and download the models files into a folder and point the training script to that folder.